# Java - How to calculate score exponentially higher based on reverse parabola

Tags: java, math

I would like the score to be exponentially higher based on how close the value is to x as illustrated in the graph below (and my apologies for the bad quality)

[image]

I know the math form `y = x^2 + ax + b` (well not exactly) however I can't get it to work in such a manner that y (the score) is higher based on close you are to x.

Comment: Do you want the parabola or not? Parabola will not get "exponentially" higher approaching its apex. Do you then want a completely different function? Note that the exponential function is very tame as far as its first derivative. You apparently want a singularity tending to infinity at x.

Comment: It's pretty exactly what darijan answered but instead of for 0 for any arbitrary x...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your function to be higher when it is closer to zero, then you should have negative coefficient in front of x^2

```
y = -1 * x^2 + ...
```

Take a look at this example at Wolfram-Alpha: [parabola](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i==%20-1%20%2a%20x%5E2%20%2b%20x%20%2b%201)

Comment: Not necessarily 0 but rather some arbitrary x value.

Comment: Found it based on your comment. Basically it's y = -1 * (x-xToRight)^2 + yAxisPeakValue